# How to get absolute paths in Hadoop Filesystem?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I would like to get a list of all files in a directory and its sub-directories in a HDFS filesystem. This is the method I've written for the purpose of recursively reading all the files in a directory:

```
def getAllFiles(dir: Path, fs: FileSystem, recursive: Boolean = true): Seq[Path] = {
  val iter = fs.listFiles(dir, recursive)
  val files = new ListBuffer[Path]()

  while (iter.hasNext()) {
    val p = iter.next().getPath
      files.append(p)
    }
    files
}
```

The result is a list of `org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path` elements which I need to process in the sub-sequent steps. Hence, I need to full path. My question is: what is the best way to get the full absolute path

So far, I use a recursive method to create the path string (Scala):

```
def fullPath(p: Path): String = {
  if (p.isRoot())
    p.getName
  else
    fullPath(p.getParent) + Path.SEPARATOR + p.getName
}
```

Is there no more straight-forward way through the Path API?

I've come across question [#18034758](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034758/hadoop-how-to-get-absolute-file-path), but using `listFiles()` rather than `listStatus()` seems to be the preferred way to recursively list files in a directory so the answer seems a bit cumbersome for this use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may not be a good idea to rely on "toString". What if the definition of toString changes. I think it is better to do something like

```
path.toUri().getRawPath()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `toString()` method in `org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path` returns the full path.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad this is not documented here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.html#toString--

Answer (score 0):

Below HDFS command will help you with absolute path prefix:

```
hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS
```